# How do I multiply two tables with many columns and rows in R for specific people?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need help to creating this output in R: I need table 1 x table 2 = Output.
I have two tables broken down by months. The first table looks like this:

| id | name | month_1 | month_2 | month_3 | month_4 | month_5 | month_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | null | null |
| 2 | Mary | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Angelo | 1 | 1 | null | null | null | null |
| 4 | Diane | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | null | null |

The second table looks like this:

| id | name | month_1 | month_2 | month_3 | month_4 | month_5 | month_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Mary | 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | Diane | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Angelo | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | John | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The output I'm hoping for is this:

| id | name | month_1 | month_2 | month_3 | month_4 | month_5 | month_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | null | null |
| 2 | Mary | 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Angelo | 1 | 5 | null | null | null | null |
| 4 | Diane | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | null | null |

Comment: Use this logic: `tbl_b[is.na(tbl_a)] <- NA`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c('id', 'name')) %>%
  transmute(id, name,
    across(ends_with('.x'), .names = '{str_remove(.col, ".x")}') *
      across(ends_with('.y')))

 id   name month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 month_6
1  1   John       3       0       1       0      NA      NA
2  2   Mary       6       1       2       1       1       2
3  3 Angelo       1       5      NA      NA      NA      NA
4  4  Diane       3       2       0       1      NA      NA
```